# Find match item in JSON array

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a SQL table called 'Interactions' and a column called `Events` that holds an array of JSON data. I am looking for any row where the Events json has any array with `@odata.type` = `#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal`

```
[
   {
      "@odata.type":"#Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.PageViewEvent",
      "CustomValues":[

      ],
      "DefinitionId":"9326cb1e-cec8-48f2-9a3e-91c7dbb2166c",
      "ItemId":"5ae02a76-ac59-4dbb-913f-3b2e51d92bae",
      "Id":"b067f72f-1d60-4773-a2e8-9d23770fea54",
      "Timestamp":"2019-11-11T17:18:31.2206225Z",
      "ItemLanguage":"en",
      "ItemVersion":1,
      "Url":"/renewal-confirmation",
      "SitecoreRenderingDevice":{
         "Id":"fe5d7fdf-89c0-4d99-9aa3-b5fbd009c9f3",
         "Name":"Default"
      }
   },
   {
      "@odata.type":"#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal",
      "CustomValues":[

      ],
      "DataKey":"/sitecore/content/Client/home/renewal-confirmation",
      "DefinitionId":"c0bc91b9-b5fc-4faa-bc12-3dba8bbae44f",
      "ItemId":"5ae02a76-ac59-4dbb-913f-3b2e51d92bae",
      "EngagementValue":100,
      "Id":"e7031fb4-ce57-459f-a9f1-2682748d3431",
      "ParentEventId":"b067f72f-1d60-4773-a2e8-9d23770fea54",
      "Timestamp":"2019-11-11T17:18:31.2518732Z"
   }
]
```

What I am currently trying is this, but no results

```
select *
from [Interactions] I
where exists
( 
  select * 
  from openjson(I.Events,'$."@odata.type"') 
  where value = '#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal'
)
```

If I use this, I can get any row where the 1st item in the array `@odata.type` = `#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal`. This works. But I want it from any item in the array.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Interactions]
WHERE JSON_VALUE([Events], '$[0]."@odata.type"') = '#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to parse the `JSON` column using `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema (`WITH` clause with columns definitions). With this approach you can filter the `Interactions` table and get information from the `JSON` data.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Interactions (
   Events nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Interactions
   (Events)
VALUES 
   (N'[
   {
      "@odata.type":"#Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.PageViewEvent",
      "CustomValues":[

      ],
      "DefinitionId":"9326cb1e-cec8-48f2-9a3e-91c7dbb2166c",
      "ItemId":"5ae02a76-ac59-4dbb-913f-3b2e51d92bae",
      "Id":"b067f72f-1d60-4773-a2e8-9d23770fea54",
      "Timestamp":"2019-11-11T17:18:31.2206225Z",
      "ItemLanguage":"en",
      "ItemVersion":1,
      "Url":"/renewal-confirmation",
      "SitecoreRenderingDevice":{
         "Id":"fe5d7fdf-89c0-4d99-9aa3-b5fbd009c9f3",
         "Name":"Default"
      }
   },
   {
      "@odata.type":"#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal",
      "CustomValues":[

      ],
      "DataKey":"/sitecore/content/Client/home/renewal-confirmation",
      "DefinitionId":"c0bc91b9-b5fc-4faa-bc12-3dba8bbae44f",
      "ItemId":"5ae02a76-ac59-4dbb-913f-3b2e51d92bae",
      "EngagementValue":100,
      "Id":"e7031fb4-ce57-459f-a9f1-2682748d3431",
      "ParentEventId":"b067f72f-1d60-4773-a2e8-9d23770fea54",
      "Timestamp":"2019-11-11T17:18:31.2518732Z"
   }
]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Interactions i
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(i.Events) WITH (
   ODataType nvarchar(100) '$."@odata.type"'
   -- and additional columns definitions 
) j
WHERE j.ODataType = '#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original query is close but doesn't work because you can't directly pick out scalars with `OPENJSON`. You want something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [interactions]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM OPENJSON([events]) WITH (
        [@odata.type] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
    WHERE [@odata.type] = '#Sitecore.XConnect.Goal'
)
```